# Use Microsoft Mail to open eml files without an email account?

Tags: windows, email-client

Windows 10/11 has a build-in app named "Mail" which is the only build-in app to see "EML" files. However, when I open it, it asks me to enter the email account authentication. While I don't need it to check my emails. Is there any way to bypass that and only use this app as an .EML viewer?

Comment: have you tried drag and dropping an EML file onto the Mail executable?

Comment: @jsotola MS Mail is a Windows 11 app and I think does not have a regular EXE file. Even if it had, it still will ask to sign in to a mail account.

Comment: @HandsomeNerd did you find a solution to this, I'm in the same situation

Comment: @Pete I installed Thunderbird instead to open EML files.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a temporary email account to the `Mail` app once, and then remove it from the app immediately.

After that you can open `.eml` files and it won't prompt you for account again. Just right-click the `.eml` file and select "Open with - Mail"

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Mail app as an EML Viewer without a MS account attached to it.

As an alternative you can use Thunderdird.

1. Install TB
2. When first launched just create an empty feed account.
3. Now you can open EML with a double click.

If you need to open also MSG file you can use MSGViewer (opensource and support EML files too). You can find it in: https://github.com/lolo101/MsgViewer/